# Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name. | Error with pip3 install mysqlclient

Tags: python-3.x, libmysqlclient

I'm getting this error:

```bash
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmphrzarweg get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpaqgu543j
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-_fp0fmz2/mysqlclient
  Complete output (22 lines):
  Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
  Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
  Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/tmphrzarweg", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "/tmp/tmphrzarweg", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/tmp/tmphrzarweg", line 114, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xwnfy9xc/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xwnfy9xc/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xwnfy9xc/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 154, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 48, in get_config_posix
    File "<string>", line 27, in find_package_name
  Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
  Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmphrzarweg get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpaqgu543j Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have python3-dev, libmysqlclient-dev and build-essential installed yet I'm still getting the error. I also have pkg-config installed.

Currently, I have python 3.8, mysql v8.0.35 and I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.6

Comment: I just specified MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually, yet I'm still getting the error